# Name for a nowhere constant function?

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a pithy name for a function  $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that there is no non-degenerate interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f$ is constant on $I$ (by '$f$ is constant on $I$', I mean that $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = f(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n)$, for all $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n), (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n) \in I$)?

Comment: Perhaps "non locally constant" would be sufficiently descriptive?  "Nowhere constant" wouldn't make since, unless it was a function that outputs a function and the output functions are never constant.

Comment: I think "nowhere constant" sounds fine. It's not more abusive than "nowhere dense" or "nowhere monotonic".

Comment: I don't think there's a name for this.  But what do you mean by an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I mean the Cartesian product $I_1 \times I_2 \times \dots \times I_n$ of $n$ intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ (at least one of which is non-degenerate).